# Adding conditional probabilities to data.table in R

Tags: r, probability, contingency

I have the titanic dataset in which I want to find the probability of survival based on 3 conditions. The following table gives the probabilities.

```
library(PASWR2)
tab = with(TITANIC3, ftable(fare = fare > 200, pclass, sex, survived)) %>% prop.table(1) %>% round(3) * 100
tab
```

Is there an easy way to add probabilities from `tab` table to TITANIC3 dataset as a new column?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be achieved by using the package `data.table`.
The object `TITANIC3` is of class `data.frame`. First you need to convert it to class `data.table`. When using data.table you can define new columns based on aggregations and a grouping clause directly in one line.
Just run the code below.

The new column with the conditional probability of survival is `survival_prob`.
I always recommend using `data.table` because it is the fastest way to manipulate data in R. However, if you want to proceed your analysis with a `data.frame`, just use the command `setDF(titanic3)` to convert the object back to class `data.frame`.

```
library(PASWR2)
library(magrittr)
library(data.table)

# convert dataset from data frame to data table 
titanic3 <- copy(TITANIC3)
setDT(titanic3)

# define new column survival_prob using by-option
titanic3[, survival_prob := round(100*mean(survived), 1), 
         by = .(fare > 200, pclass, sex)]
```

Comment: I have a follow-up question on the same, I will appreciate if you can look at this. - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64680211/survival-probability-based-on-continuous-variable-in-r

Comment: I posted an answer to your question.

Comment: Thanks, stats_guy. I have accepted your answer. Really appreciate you taking time to answer my query.